# ProgressDialog in AsyncTask throws an exception

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I'm trying to make a simple `ProgressDialog` appear while my `AsyncTask` is fetching data. In my `onPreExecute()` method I have this:

```
pd = ProgressDialog.show(c, "Loading...", "Please wait");
```

`c` is the context passed into the constructor of my `AsyncTask` from `this.getApplicationContext()`. Unfortunately, I keep getting an exception with this message:

> Unable to add window -- Token null is not for an application

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:** Using `this` instead of `this.getApplicationContext()` has revealed another problem. When I call `ProgressDialog.show(...`, a ProgressDialog is displayed, but not until after the `AsyncTask` has completed. In other words, the data loads and then the dialog is displayed. If I include `pd.dismiss()` in my `onPostExecute()` then I never even see the dialog (presumable because it is closed before it ever gets opened).

**Final solution:** It turns out that `fetch.get()` was hogging the UI thread and not letting the ProgressDialog display.

Comment: This question has been answered

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561803/android-progressdialog-show-crashes-with-getapplicationcontext

Comment: Ally - Thanks, but I'm not sure its the exactly the same issue. The accepted solution is about an Android bug that was supposedly fixed in 1.6 (I'm using 2.1). I did find another solution, which is to create a static method in the main activity to display the ProgressDialog. This has the same issue, where the dialog is not being displayed until AFTER the data has already been loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ProgressDialog dialog;
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(viewContacts.this);
        dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.please_wait_while_loading));
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: This gives the exact same exception.

Comment: Then is something wrong with your Context. Change that from `this.getApplicationContext()` to just `this` when you pass it. Or if the AsyncTask is private to a Context class, just use the reference to the outer class as `MyClass.this`

Comment: Using `this` instead of `this.getApplicationContext()` gets rid of the exception, but no dialog is displayed. (`pd.dismiss()` in `onPostExecute` also runs without error.)

Comment: @Computerish try looking into the samples in your SDK folder, and above my example, it simply works for an Activity that has no dialogs displayed

Comment: Using `this` instead of `this.getApplicationContext()` has revealed another problem. When I call `ProgressDialog.show(...`, a ProgressDialog is displayed, but not until after the `AsyncTask` has completed. In other words, the data loads and then the dialog is displayed. If I include `pd.dismiss()` in my `onPostExecute()` then I never even see the dialog (presumable because it is closed before it ever gets opened).

Comment: Please post the whole code of your AsyncTask, and the method where you call execute(). Edit the original question.

Comment: There you go! Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I don't see anything odd there, just that you call `fetcher.get()` right after you execute the task which runs in asynchronous way, so it will finish long after your code is executed.

Comment: Could it be that the UI thread is busy waiting for the AsyncTask to finish, so it can't display the ProgressDialog? What should I do to prevent this?

Comment: I don't see that happening. Check the sample apps from your SDK samples folder.

Comment: Ok, so I discovered that if I remove the `fetch.get()` line (the one that is hogging the UI thread), the ProgressDialog works, but now the results obviously aren't being displayed. How can I update an `ImageView` from my `AsyncTask`?

Comment: You can do some change in your interface in the `onProgressUpdate` method, or the `onPostExecute` both run on the UI thread. Whichever is suitable for you.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  this.pd = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Loading...", "Please wait", true, false);
```

and yes I think the same the problem is with your context.

Comment: Using `this` instead of `this.getApplicationContext()` gets rid of the exception, but no dialog is displayed. (`pd.dismiss()` in `onPostExecute` also runs without error.)

Comment: Using `this` instead of `this.getApplicationContext()` has revealed another problem. When I call `ProgressDialog.show(...`, a ProgressDialog is displayed, but not until after the `AsyncTask` has completed. In other words, the data loads and then the dialog is displayed. If I include `pd.dismiss()` in my `onPostExecute()` then I never even see the dialog (presumable because it is closed before it ever gets opened).

Answer (score 0):

Use `YourClassName.this` instead of using `getApplicationContext()` or `this.getApplicationContext()`