# Application context for SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Can I use `ApplicationContext` for working with `SharedPreferences` and starting, for example, `RemoteService`?

Logically, I think that I can. Are there any nuances in such an approach?

Comment: What is wrong with this question?
Is it too dummy?

Comment: Think there are no people seen the question who can give an answer :(

Comment: Look at this, it may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987072/using-application-context-everywhere

Comment: @user1074896 I've seen your comments and thought a little bounty mi8 help; and it did :P

Comment: Extending Ajay answer, there is a good explanation here: [SharedPreferences application context vs activity context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11567134/sharedpreferences-application-context-vs-activity-context)

Answer (score 14):

as Gunnar Karlsson mentioned ContextWrapper's [getApplicationContext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getApplicationContext%28%29) usage its pretty clear that you should only use `Activity` or `Service` **Context** to **register/unregister** your receiver, bind/unbind your services (*unless it is really required to register with static data, not a particular component*) to avoid uncertain memory leaks and to be safe even if you forget sometimes to unregister, the system will clear it for you with warnings.
 But, for `getSharedPreferences(...)` you can always use any `ApplicationContext` or `Context` without a hitch. The [reason](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) is, it has been clearly mentioned

> For any particular set of preferences(here **SharedPreferences**), there is a single instance of
> this class that all **clients** share.

Getting only a reference via application context will not keep the reference forever. It's just a reference to the preferences via application context like any other. So it will be cleared as soon as the user is done with it.

Please note, registering a receiver via application context will be maintained as global state associated with your application. So it will never be cleared for you.

Please someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @Toro, Please add your findings to support the comment. Eventually, all the users should know why you think the above answer is in correct.

Answer (score 10):

You should use the `Activity` or `Service` `Context`, i.e. `'this'`, unless you have a clear and strong reason not to. Only use `ApplicationContext` if you clearly need a reference to the global state of your application.

From Android Developers API docs on [`ContextWrapper's` `getApplicationContext()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getApplicationContext%28%29) method:

> This generally should only be used if you need a Context whose lifecycle is separate from the current context, that is tied to the lifetime of the process rather than the current component.

and

> using the ApplicationContext (...) [as opposed to e.g. an Activity or Service context] can easily lead to serious leaks if you forget to unregister, unbind, etc.

For example, to retrieve `SharedPreferences` in an `Activity` to e.g. change data displayed to the user, use `this.getSharedPreferences(...)` since there is no clear reason why you would need to tap into the application's lifecycle. Same, in a `Service`, use `this.getSharedPreferences(...)`. (Note that Activity and Service  *are* Contexts. They indirectly extend `android.content.Context`)

CommonsWare has written an in-depth answer: [When to call activity context OR application context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context) where he makes the case that calling getApplicationContext() `"is almost always wrong"` and outlines the few exceptions when to use it:

- bind to a Service from an Activity.
- something needs to be tied to a Context with global scope.

CommonsWare also links to an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228160/what-exactly-does-using-the-application-context-mean/5228494#5228494) by Android Framework Engineer Dianne Hackborn:

> The first rule I would give you: if you don't know why you need [Application Context], you probably don't need it (...)The only time you want to use getApplicationContext() is when you need a Context that exists outside of the lifecycle of an Activity class (or other component).

More answers on the same subject with discussions on the issues relating to `ApplicationContext`:

- [Android: ProgressDialog.show() crashes with getApplicationContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561803/android-progressdialog-show-crashes-with-getapplicationcontext)
- [Difference between Activity Context and Application Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128589/difference-between-activity-context-and-application-context)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `getApplicationContext()` for that. You can use `getApplicationContext()` anywhere you use `getBaseContext()` or the `this` keyword when in an Activity or Service, except for very specific cases like when adding Views or Dialogs to the UI.

[Here](http://www.levinotik.com/2011/10/12/demystifying-context-in-android/) is an excellent article on what Context is and what is does, which I would definitely recommend going through.