# How many types of context in android and what is better to use

Tags: android, android-context

I just wanted to know how many ways to get the context, which method used in which situation.
Which one better to use, and what is the main and key deference between them.

Comment: check this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context)

Comment: Hi puja http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128589/difference-between-activity-context-and-application-context   chech this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Your better understands you should read android official blog. an also look at [HackBod Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228160/what-exactly-does-using-the-application-context-mean/5228494#5228494).

There are some references URL which help you more about the context

1. [What exactly does using the Application Context mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228160/what-exactly-does-using-the-application-context-mean/5228494#5228494)
2. [Difference between Activity Context and Application Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128589/difference-between-activity-context-and-application-context)
3. http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Thanks

Comment: Third link is also important because using wrong contexts can cause memory leaks too!

Answer (score 2):

`Context` class represents the local environment of an App, It encapsulates all the services and resources available to the app. There is a base class `ApplicationContext`, and sub classes for components: `Activity`, `Service` etc.

Always prefer using `ApplicationContext` because it is global and doesn't cause serious issues if its leaked, that is: an unused reference of it stays and is not garbage collected.

Sometimes you have to use sub components like `Activity` or `Service` as context. Use this when creating Intents, or creating UI Elements, or showing a toast etc. That is: functions that are specifically bound to these component's identity, its UI or its display window.