# Loading images from firebase (whole folders to RecyclerView)

Tags: android

There is a lot of posts how to laod image from firebase but I still don't understand them. My code does nothing so please give me an example method.

I can't understand how to use the Glide or Picasso what to insert into `.with` `.load` and `.into`.
My goal is to load everything from whole category and display it in one fragment.  My firebase storage structure (I attached json):

```
{
"Category1": {
    "01": {
        "imageLink": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/wallex0111.appspot.com/o/photo_2018-10-19_21-38-21.jpg?alt=media&token=f1d29e64-a9ca-4c71-aba7-8144992c835e",
    },
    "02": {
        "imageLink": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/wallex0111.appspot.com/o/photo_2018-10-31_10-38-06.jpg?alt=media&token=6889a3b8-3691-41ea-9162-91558ba4181b",
    },
    "03": {
        "imageLink": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/wallex0111.appspot.com/o/photo_2018-10-06_14-19-41.jpg?alt=media&token=e75b0096-aaf5-4952-827b-7efb71d6723c",
    }
},
"Category2": {
    "01": {
        "imageLink": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/wallex0111.appspot.com/o/photo_2018-10-07_13-55-55.jpg?alt=media&token=bd37d98c-215a-4caf-bf37-d43d78736c31",
    },
    "02": {
        "imageLink": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/wallex0111.appspot.com/o/photo_2018-10-31_10-38-06.jpg?alt=media&token=6889a3b8-3691-41ea-9162-91558ba4181b",
    }
}
```

}

Fragment

```
public class AllFrtagment extends Fragment {}
```

xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Fragments.AllFrtagment">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relLayyout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relLayyout1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="60">

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gridView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="40"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
                android:numColumns="5"
                android:stretchMode="none"
                android:verticalSpacing="1dp"></GridView>
            <!--I think that using GridView is all I need...? Without additional ImageView-->
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/galleryImageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need so many nested views (assuming you only want to load images). A `RecyclerView` is enough

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".Fragments.AllFrtagment">

        <RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Parse your json into a model class.
Create a [recyclerview](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-the-RecyclerView) and pass your list of imageLinks to the recyclerview adapter.
and use any image library to show your images.

Lets talk Glide now.

```
GlideApp.with(context) //with(), takes your context
.load(imageUrl) //load(), takes your image url
.into(galleryImageView); // Your ImageView is where the image will be shown.
```

Comment: How exactly should adapter look? What do you mean: "image library"?

Comment: I meant Glide, Picasso etc.
I linked how to work with recycler view. give it a read, that will guide you
(https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-the-RecyclerView)

Comment: What would be my context? In load I don't want to pass simply link because I want to add photos in firebase and then they will be updated without editing app code. So my category should be lined in some way.

Comment: inside your fragment you can use getActivity() as your context.
read more on context https://stackoverflow.com/a/17873942/6207294

Answer (score 0):

**Using Picasso**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
  android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

Picasso.get().load(city.getImage())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .into(holder.image);
```

- You can find the complete [sample/CityPreview](https://github.com/KhaledLela/CityPreview) app on Github

Comment: This app explained me a lot but I would by really grateful if you would explain me how to load these photos from firebase. I need to build an app in which I won't have to update code for every added image.

Comment: Checkout [firebase doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup), [**Google firebase database sample**](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/database).