# The view is not attached to a window

Tags: android, debugging, android-logcat

What does the warning `The view is not attached to a window` mean? I am constantly getting it in Logcat, while trying to debug my game.

**The exact output:**

```
12-27 18:14:12.415: W/View(16827): The view is not attached to a window
```

I've searched for this warning and couldn't find anything on it. All I got was the [error about Window Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612842/view-not-attached-to-window-manager), which is not what am I getting here. I want to know the reason for this warning, just to confirm if it's related to the FPS drop?

Comment: Have you solved this problem since that time?

Comment: The question is old. I've already finished the project. I still don't have any idea about the warning message. Although the FPS drop was due to some other issue.

Comment: Yes, I saw that it is old. Just encountered this myself, but this was not a game. I think it's a bug specific for a concrete device...

Comment: Yeah I guess so, try to debug on any other device. Probably you can solve the mystery ;-)

Comment: I saw this only on one device, and that device is known for having strange issues. But if I can know what the heck these messages mean...

Comment: @SargeBorsch what device you had tested on?

Comment: @Vyacheslav I can't recall now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that you have any **dialog box** running while the orientation changes. Just dismiss the dialog in your onFinish or onDestroy of the activity.