# Passing Data from one activity to another Toast message giving error

Tags: android, object

I create an object in my Createprofile class and pass an ID value through the same to my CreateProfile1 class:

Code in my CreateProfile class:

```
public class CreateProfile extends Activity {


TextView tv;
private static final int PICK_FROM_CAMERA = 1;
private static final int PICK_FROM_GALLERY = 2;
ImageView imgview;
int z=0; 
byte b[];
ImageView img;
EditText Idno = null;
EditText GIDno=null;
EditText Name= null;
EditText Owner= null;
EditText Date=null;
AutoCompleteTextView Breed = null;
private DBAdapter DBHelper = null;
private CreateProfile1 PF = null;
String name, ID,GID,ow,br,date;
private EditText mDateDisplay;
private int mYear;
private int mMonth;
private int mDay;
static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 1;
String mm="";

 public void auto(){
        // Get a reference to the AutoCompleteTextView in the layout
        AutoCompleteTextView txtView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_breed);
        // Get the string array
        String[] breed = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries_array);
        // Create the adapter and set it to the AutoCompleteTextView 
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, breed);
        txtView.setThreshold(1);
        txtView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

 public int radiox(){

     RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup1);
     int checkedRadioButton = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
     int a=0;

     switch (checkedRadioButton) {
            case R.id.radiobutton3 : 
                    a = 1;
                    break;
            case R.id.radiobutton4 : 
                    a = 2;
                    break;  
            case R.id.radiobutton5 : 
                    a = 3;
                    break;                        
            }
     return a;
     }

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.profile);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    DBHelper = new DBAdapter(this);
    PF = new CreateProfile1();

    //MediaPlayer MyMp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.robo);
    //MyMp.start();
    String fontPath = "fonts/COPRGTB.TTF";

    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    TextView tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    TextView tv3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView8);
    TextView tv4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    TextView tv5=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    TextView tv6=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    TextView tv8=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView9);
    TextView tv9=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView10);
    Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    //button.setOnClickListener(sav);
    RadioButton r1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radiobutton3);
    RadioButton r2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radiobutton4);
    RadioButton r3=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radiobutton5);


    // Loading Font Face
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontPath);

    // Applying font
    tv.setTypeface(tf);
    tv1.setTypeface(tf);
    tv2.setTypeface(tf);
    tv3.setTypeface(tf);
    tv4.setTypeface(tf);
    tv5.setTypeface(tf);
    tv6.setTypeface(tf);
    tv8.setTypeface(tf);
    tv9.setTypeface(tf);
    button.setTypeface(tf);
    r1.setTypeface(tf);
    r2.setTypeface(tf);
    r3.setTypeface(tf);
    auto();


    Idno = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    GIDno = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextx);
    Name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    Owner = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    Breed = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_breed);
    Date = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    Button Save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    Save.setOnClickListener(onSave);
 //   Button check=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnx);
 //   check.setOnClickListener(oncheck);



   Button pic=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
   imgview = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
   pic.setOnClickListener(picc);

      //for datepicker

      mDateDisplay = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
      Button pickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
      pickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                    showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            }
    });
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    updateDisplay();
}
  //for date picker
   protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    mDateSetListener,
                    mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    }
    return null;
}
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) 
{
    switch (id) 
    {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            ((DatePickerDialog) dialog).updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            break;
    }
}    
private void updateDisplay() 
{

      int month=mMonth+1;

      if(month==1)
      {
          mm="Jan";
      }
      else if(month==2)
      {
            mm="Feb";
      }
      else if(month==3)
      {
            mm="Mar";
      }
      else if(month==4)
      {
            mm="Apr";
      }
      else if(month==5)
      {
            mm="May";
      }
      else if(month==6)
      {
            mm="Jun";
      }

      else if(month==7)
      {
            mm="Jul";
      }
      else  if(month==8)
      {
           mm="Aug";
      }
      else  if(month==9)
      {
           mm="Sep";
      }
      else  if(month==10)
      {
           mm="Oct";
      }

      else  if(month==11)
      {
           mm="Nov";
      }

      else  if(month==12)
      {
           mm="Dec";
      }



    mDateDisplay.setText
    (
            new StringBuilder()



            // Month is 0 based so add 1
            .append(mDay).append("-")
           // .append(mMonth + 1).append("-")
            .append(mm).append("-")

            .append(mYear).append(" "));
    }
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,int dayOfMonth) {
            mYear = year;
            mMonth = monthOfYear;
            mDay = dayOfMonth;
            updateDisplay();

    }
};

 //for camera
private View.OnClickListener picc=new View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {

         openNewGameDialog();   

    }
};

 private void openNewGameDialog() 
 {
             new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setItems(R.array.Menu2,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
             {
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface,int i) 
             {
                if(i==0)
                {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString());
                    // ******** code for crop image
                    intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
                    intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
                    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
                    intent.putExtra("outputX", 110);
                    intent.putExtra("outputY", 60);

                    try 
                    {

                    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);

                    }
                    catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
                    {
                    // Do nothing for now
                    }

             // Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
             //   startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST); 



                //Intent CreateProfile = new Intent(MenuScreen.this,CreateProfile.class);
                //startActivity(CreateProfile);
                }
                else if (i==1)
                {


                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        // call android default gallery
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        // ******** code for crop image
                        intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
                        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
                        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
                        intent.putExtra("outputX", 110);
                        intent.putExtra("outputY", 60);

                        try 
                        {

                        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                        "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_GALLERY);

                        } 
                        catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) 
                        {
                        // Do nothing for now
                        }


                //  Intent CheckProfile = new Intent(MenuScreen.this,CreateProfile.class);
                //  startActivity(CheckProfile);

                //  Intent gal = new Intent(
                //          Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                //          android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                //  startActivityForResult(gal, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

                }

            }
            })
            .show();
    }

 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
 {

     if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_CAMERA) 
     {
         Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
         if (extras != null)
            {
             Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
             imgview.setImageBitmap(photo);

             ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
             photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos); //photo is the bitmap object   
             b = baos.toByteArray(); 

            }
     }

     if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY) 
     {
            Bundle extras2 = data.getExtras();
            if (extras2 != null) 
            {
            Bitmap photo = extras2.getParcelable("data");
            imgview.setImageBitmap(photo);

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
            photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos); //photo is the bitmap object   
            b = baos.toByteArray();

            }
     }
 }
private View.OnClickListener onSave=new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v){
        DBHelper.open();
        boolean y =false;
        y = fillData();
        z = radiox();
        br= Breed.getText().toString();
        ow= Owner.getText().toString();
        GID = GIDno.getText().toString();

        boolean k = false;
        boolean r = false; 
        boolean d = false; 
        boolean o=false;
        boolean p=false;
        o=datevalidation();
        if (o){
            Date.setError("Your Horse can't be born in the future");
            p=true;
        }
        else{
            date= Date.getText().toString();
        }
        if (z==0){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select Gender", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            k=true;
        }
        if(Name.getText().toString().length() < 2 ){
            Name.setError( "Enter Name" );
            r=true;
        }
        else{
            name = Name.getText().toString();
        }
        if(y==true || Idno.getText().toString().length()<1){
            Idno.setError("Enter a Unique ID");
            d=true;
        }
        else{
            ID= Idno.getText().toString();
        }
            if(k==false && r == false && d == false && p ==false){
            DBHelper.insertD(ID, GID, name, ow, br,z,date, b);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Database Created And Data Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent profiletwo = new Intent(CreateProfile.this,CreateProfile1.class);
            startActivity(profiletwo);
            DBHelper.close();
            PF.getid(ID);
        }
        else if(k==true || r==true || d ==true || p == true){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please check if form Data is entered correctly", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
};

private boolean fillData() {
    Cursor c = DBHelper.fetchAllIDs();
    boolean x = false;
   // List<String> idList = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String X = (c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("IDno")));
            String B = null; 
            B = Idno.getText().toString();
            if (B.equals(X)){
                x=true;
            }
        } while (c.moveToNext());


    }
    return x;
}
public boolean datevalidation(){
    boolean m= false;
    Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
    today.setToNow();
    int a = today.monthDay;
    int b = (today.month+1);
    int c = today.year;

    if (mYear > c){
        m=true;
    }
    if (mYear==c && (mMonth+1)>b){
        m=true;
    }
    if(mYear==c && (mMonth+1) == b && mDay >a){
        m=true;
    }
    return m; 
}
```

}

My CreateProfile1 Class goes like this:

```
    public class CreateProfile1 extends Activity {
Context context;
String Identity= null; 
public int VID;
public int DateDay;
public int DateMonth;
int DateYear; 
int hours,minutes; 
public void getid(String ID){
    Identity = ID;
}
public void getVaccination(int VacciID){
    VID = VacciID;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+VID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void getDate(int mYear, int mMonth, int mDay){
    DateYear = mYear; 
    DateMonth = mMonth;
    DateDay = mDay; 
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+DateYear+DateMonth+DateDay, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
public void getTime(int Hours, int Minutes){
    hours = Hours;
    minutes=Minutes;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+hours+minutes, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.profile1);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    String fontPath = "fonts/COPRGTB.TTF";



    TextView tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    TextView tv3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    TextView tv4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    TextView tv5=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);

    Button button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button button3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);


    button3.setOnClickListener(vaccination);

    Button button4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    Button button5=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
    Button button6=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);
    Button button7=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button7);

    button1.setOnClickListener(onButton1);
    button2.setOnClickListener(deworming);


    // Loading Font Face
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontPath);

    // Applying font

    tv1.setTypeface(tf);
    tv2.setTypeface(tf);
    tv3.setTypeface(tf);
    tv4.setTypeface(tf);
    tv5.setTypeface(tf);

    button1.setTypeface(tf);
    button2.setTypeface(tf);
    button3.setTypeface(tf);
    button4.setTypeface(tf);
    button5.setTypeface(tf);
    button6.setTypeface(tf);
    button7.setTypeface(tf);  
}

private View.OnClickListener onButton1=new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v){
         File pdfFile = new File("/sdcard/" +"BCS.pdf"); 
         if(pdfFile.exists()) {

             Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile); 
             Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
             pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
             pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
             try{
                 startActivity(pdfIntent);
             }
             catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
                 Toast.makeText(CreateProfile1.this, "File does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+VID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+Identity, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


             }
         }
    }
};

private View.OnClickListener vaccination=new View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {

        Intent vaccin = new Intent(CreateProfile1.this,Vaccination.class);
        startActivity(vaccin);

    }
};


private View.OnClickListener deworming=new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){

        Intent Deworm = new Intent(CreateProfile1.this,DeWorming.class);
        startActivity(Deworm);

    }
};
```

The log Cat display:

```
    10-08 14:12:56.603: D/dalvikvm(329): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 51K, 53% free     2563K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 42ms
    10-08 14:12:57.454: E/tag(329): fonts
    10-08 14:12:57.454: E/tag(329): images
    10-08 14:12:57.454: E/tag(329): sounds
    10-08 14:12:57.454: E/tag(329): webkit
    10-08 14:13:02.813: D/dalvikvm(329): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 16K, 52% free    2584K/5379K, external 3502K/3903K, paused 41ms
    10-08 14:13:34.544: W/KeyCharacterMap(329): No keyboard for id 0
    10-08 14:13:34.544: W/KeyCharacterMap(329): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
    10-08 14:13:44.894: D/AndroidRuntime(329): Shutting down VM
    10-08 14:13:44.894: W/dalvikvm(329): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
    10-08 14:13:44.903: E/AndroidRuntime(329): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    10-08 14:13:44.903: E/AndroidRuntime(329): java.lang.NullPointerException
    10-08 14:13:44.903: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:100)
    10-08 14:13:44.903: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at com.gallops.CreateProfile1.getid(CreateProfile1.java:24)
    10-08 14:13:44.903: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at com.gallops.CreateProfile$3.onClick(CreateProfile.java:446)
    10-08 14:13:44.903: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
    10-08 14:13:44.903: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
    10-08 14:13:44.903: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    10-08 14:13:44.903: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    10-08 14:13:44.903: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    10-08 14:13:44.903: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    10-08 14:13:44.903: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    10-08 14:13:44.903: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    10-08 14:13:44.903: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    10-08 14:13:44.903: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    10-08 14:13:44.903: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    10-08 14:18:45.614: D/dalvikvm(344): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 57K, 53% free 2567K/5379K, external 2002K/2137K, paused 41ms
```

The Log Cat display after using:

```
    Toast.makeText(CreateProfile1.this, ""+Identity, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    10-08 14:30:20.313: D/dalvikvm(329): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 51K, 53% free 2563K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 41ms
    10-08 14:30:21.052: E/tag(329): fonts
    10-08 14:30:21.052: E/tag(329): images
    10-08 14:30:21.052: E/tag(329): sounds
    10-08 14:30:21.052: E/tag(329): webkit
    10-08 14:30:24.072: D/dalvikvm(329): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 17K, 52% free 2586K/5379K, external 3502K/3903K, paused 34ms
    10-08 14:30:31.993: W/KeyCharacterMap(329): No keyboard for id 0
    10-08 14:30:31.993: W/KeyCharacterMap(329): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
    10-08 14:30:42.053: D/AndroidRuntime(329): Shutting down VM
    10-08 14:30:42.053: W/dalvikvm(329): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
   10-08 14:30:42.062: E/AndroidRuntime(329): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   10-08 14:30:42.062: E/AndroidRuntime(329): java.lang.NullPointerException
   10-08 14:30:42.062: E/AndroidRuntime(329):   at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:80)
   10-08 14:30:42.062: E/AndroidRuntime(329):   at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:89)
   10-08 14:30:42.062: E/AndroidRuntime(329):   at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:231)
   10-08 14:30:42.062: E/AndroidRuntime(329):   at com.gallops.CreateProfile1.getid(CreateProfile1.java:26)
   10-08 14:30:42.062: E/AndroidRuntime(329):   at com.gallops.CreateProfile$3.onClick(CreateProfile.java:446)
   10-08 14:30:42.062: E/AndroidRuntime(329):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
   10-08 14:30:42.062: E/AndroidRuntime(329):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
   10-08 14:30:42.062: E/AndroidRuntime(329):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    10-08 14:30:42.062: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    10-08 14:30:42.062: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    10-08 14:30:42.062: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    10-08 14:30:42.062: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    10-08 14:30:42.062: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    10-08 14:30:42.062: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    10-08 14:30:42.062: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    10-08 14:30:42.062: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I have declared Identity as String Identity = null; in my CreateProfile1 class right under the class declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using **ApplicationContext** use your Activity's Context. Replace **getApplicationContext**() with your Activity Context like this,

```
Toast.makeText(ActivityName.this, ""+Identity, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

To know the difference between these context [read this.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4128589/603744)

Comment: It still gives me the error, I will update the log cat display as this time the error seems to be different.

Comment: Are you by any chance finishing the activity before the Toast displays?

Comment: Yes! But that is the previous Activity from where I port the ID value through an object!

Comment: This is really strange. Can you post the Activity's code, to find if anything is wrong.

Comment: Yes Sure I will Post both the Classes here.