# using getApplicationContext() in two threads

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a main class "A". That calls a method in class "B". In class A I pass the parameter getAplicationContext() to the method in B.

That method in "B" class is where `tempContext` is a Context object (Global):

```
    public void backit(Context con) throws Exception {                
    tempContext = con;
            Completion perThread;
    perThread = new Completion();

    perThread.start();

}
```

The Completion Class is:

```
public class Completion extends Thread {
        ProgressDialog progDialog;
        int maxvalue;

        public void run() {
            maxvalue = BackupOperation.con_num;
            progDialog = new ProgressDialog(tempContext);               
            Log.d("TEST", "HELLO");
        }

    }
```

My application force closes. With exceptions:

```
12-04 22:41:28.984: W/dalvikvm(19517): threadid=10: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40af3228)
12-04 22:41:29.104: E/AndroidRuntime(19517): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-15840
12-04 22:41:29.104: E/AndroidRuntime(19517): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
12-04 22:41:29.104: E/AndroidRuntime(19517):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
12-04 22:41:29.104: E/AndroidRuntime(19517):    at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:127)
12-04 22:41:29.104: E/AndroidRuntime(19517):    at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:114)
12-04 22:41:29.104: E/AndroidRuntime(19517):    at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:98)
12-04 22:41:29.104: E/AndroidRuntime(19517):    at android.app.ProgressDialog.<init>(ProgressDialog.java:77)
```

I can figure out that `tempContext` when i refer it in the thread, my application force closes. Any suggestions on how to get the application context in that thread?

Comment: why do you have progress dialog in a thread?

Comment: I'm just a begineer. Can you suggest me any other way?

Comment: Remove progDialog = new ProgressDialog(tempContext); on run method. Maybe you're doing confusion inside your code.

Answer (score 0):

See this discussion about the difference between an `Activity` `Context` and an `Application` `Context`:
[Difference between Activity Context and Application Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128589/difference-between-activity-context-and-application-context)

For instance, take this demonstration of a `ProgressDialog`:  http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/androids-indeterminate-progressdialog-tutorial/
(It has downloadable source to make it easy to experiment with.)
It displays a `ProgressDialog` in the `onClick()` method.  If you change the line

```
pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
```

which is using the `Activity` as the `context`, to

```
pd = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
```

it will crash.

So, if you can pass your `Activity` as the `Context`, you should be fine.