# Application vs Activity Context in Android

Tags: android

I am noob in Android. I see there are many methods associated to get context either activity or application context. What context you should use in what scenario ??

One [blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html) saying to use the context-application instead of a context-activity to avoid memory leaks. How here memory can be leaked if I use `Activity` context

Any idea ???

Comment: this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context) is very good for your asking)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between Activity Context and Application Context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128589/difference-between-activity-context-and-application-context)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026973/android-whats-the-difference-between-the-various-methods-to-get-a-context
refer this

Comment: @PankajKumar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128589/difference-between-activity-context-and-application-context#comment6225673_4128799 See here one guy saying to use `getApplicationContext` other memory leak how here memory leak can be ??

Comment: @Mick Read http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html blog carefully

Comment: @PankajKumar I have read edited my question

Comment: http://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/

Answer (score 1):

You create one Method that returns `Context(this)`. Parse `Activity` to `Application` as below (under `Methods` defined in `MainActivity` class):

```
public Context getContext() {
        return getApplicationContext();
 }
public Activity getActivity() {
        return this;
 }
```

and then use:

```
Application abc = ((Application)getActivity());
```