# Android-AlertDialog with this and getApplicationContext()

Tags: android, this, android-alertdialog, android-context

Why AlertDialog work with the tag "this" but not with the tag "getApplicationContext()"

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); //work
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext()); //doesn't Work
```

why it is so ?

Comment: Read this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128589/difference-between-activity-context-and-application-context

Comment: Ok, thanks :) for the link