# Memory leak pass context to separate file fun. Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-memory

In my Activity class :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.content_main)
        initAdds()
    }

    fun initAdds() {
        MobileAds.initialize(this) {}
        MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(
            Builder()
                .setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("ABCDEF012345"))
                .build()
        )
    }
}
```

I want to put `initAdds()` fun to separate util.kt file passing context as parameter:

```
fun initAdds(context: Context) {
    MobileAds.initialize(context) {}
    MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(
        RequestConfiguration.Builder()
            .setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("ABCDEF012345"))
            .build()
    )
}
```

Would not it cause any memory leaks?

Comment: No it will not leaks memory but you should always pass `ApplicationContext` for safety.

Comment: See this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47192857/9167710