# what is the activity name in anonymous class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, anonymous-class

Hello I'm new to **android** and I'm confused with this keyword in activity contexts. Here is a code snippet which simply prints to the screen when a button is pressed. But the studio is raising an issue.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d("My app","onCreate is called");
    Toast1("onCreate");
    Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("My app","Button is pressed");
            Toast.makeText(this,"Button pressed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//Here is a error
        }
    });
}
```

How to know which activity or class the this keyword referencing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128589/difference-between-activity-context-and-application-context read this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside anonymous class, `this` refers to the block of the anonymous class. To refer to the Activity class which contains the anonymous class, you need to append the class name and `.` before the `this` keyword

```
ActivityClassName.this
```

`Toast` either requires the context of the activity on which it is to be displayed or the context of the application

**Toast using activity context**

```
Toast.makeText(Activityname.this,"Button pressed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**Note:** If your `Toast` is inside any anonymous class, then you need to use `ActivityName.this`. If that's not the case, simply using `this` would do the job.

**Toast using application context**

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Button pressed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Isn't the context is the class covering the method?.So the context of Toast here should be the anonymous class

Answer (score 1):

If The activity that you use Called "**MyActivity**" then you can do the following:

```
MyActivity.this
```

This chunk of code will return the this "current" object of outer class
this will work for you.

```
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d("My app","onCreate is called");
    Toast1("onCreate");
    Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("My app","Button is pressed");
            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this
    ,"Button pressed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//here is the working code for you
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For toasts, which are short-lived, you can usually use whatever context you want. Typically, you would use the activity context, but application context is fine as well.

So you can use Classname.this Eg:- MainActivity.this  or getApplicationContext();

Answer (score 1):

Basically `onClick(View v)` method is anonymous class which implements method of interface `android.view.View.onClickListner` so only `this` keyword of context doesn't belong to anonymous class

so you may define reference of `this` keyword with related `Activity` in button `onClickListner`  like below code

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("My app","Button is pressed");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Button pressed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  //Change here
    }
});
```

for more reference check [this link](https://www.quora.com/In-Android-coding-what-does-MainActivity-this-do-and-what-are-MainActivity-and-this-separately-class-keyword-etc)