# Error with getApplicationContext(), Dialogs

Tags: android

I can't create a Pogress dialog, because, `getApplicationContext()`, return null

> Problem to create ProgressDialog

```
public void Diag(Boolean Show){
    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
    if (Show){
        // (Dialog) Wait time
        dialog.setMessage("Iniciando sesión...");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }else{
        dialog.dismiss(); // (Dialog) End Wait
    }
}
```

> Error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{RubenPX.ROX/RubenPX.ROX.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
```

---

**EDIT:**

> I tried this, but not work

```
public class Diag extends Application{
    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
    public void Show(){
        // (Dialog) Wait time
        dialog.setMessage("Iniciando sesión...");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }

    public void Dimiss(){
        dialog.dismiss(); // (Dialog) End Wait
    }
}
```

Comment: dialog always created by the activity context

Comment: its never created by application context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Activity Context intead of using application context

**Like this:**

```
public void Diag(Boolean Show, Context context){
    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    if (Show){
        // (Dialog) Wait time
        dialog.setMessage("Iniciando sesión...");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }else{
        dialog.dismiss(); // (Dialog) End Wait
    }
}
```

Must read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128589/difference-between-activity-context-and-application-context)