# activity context vs application context

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-context

If I'm using a one activity multiple fragments design for my app, would the application context in this case be the same as the activity context? I know it's a bad idea to pass the activity context to a ViewModel but in this case is it valid? (The app is always in portrait)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Activity Context and Application Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128589/difference-between-activity-context-and-application-context)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I'm using a one activity multiple fragments design for my app, would the application context in this case be the same as the activity context?

No. The `Application` singleton is an entirely separate class.

> I know it's a bad idea to pass the activity context to a ViewModel but in this case is it valid?

No — use the `Application`.

> The app is always in portrait

Note that there are many configuration changes, not just orientation. The user can switch locale, enable "dark mode" on Android 10+, enter or leave split-screen mode, resize a Chrome OS window, etc.