# Toast cannot show on the screen sometimes

Tags: android

I write a `ToastUtils` to avoid duplicate toast:

```java
public class ToastUtils {
    private ToastUtils() {
        //no instance
    }

    private static Toast toast = null;

    public static void showToast(String message) {
        if (toast == null) {
            toast = Toast.makeText(Utils.getApp(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
        toast.setText(message);
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }

    public static void showToast(@StringRes int messageId) {
        if (toast == null) {
            toast = Toast.makeText(Utils.getApp(), messageId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
        toast.setText(messageId);
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }

}
```

`Utils.java` is the following:

```java
public class Utils {
    private Utils() {
        //no instance
    }

    /**
     * 提供统一的 Context 接口给其他工具类
     *
     * @return Context 对象
     */
    public static Context getApp() {
        return App.getApplication();
    }

}
```

`App.java` is my custom `Application`:

```java
public class App extends Application {

    private static App application;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        application = this;
        String curProcessName = getCurProcessName();
        if (!TextUtils.equals(curProcessName, getPackageName())) {
            return;
        }
        // omit my business code...
    }


    public static App getApplication() {
        return application;
    }

    private String getCurProcessName() {
        int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (am == null || am.getRunningAppProcesses() == null || am.getRunningAppProcesses().isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : am.getRunningAppProcesses()) {
            if (appProcess.pid == pid) {
                return appProcess.processName;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

What makes me frustrated is `ToastUtils` doesn't work sometimes, ie, I cannot see toast message show on the screen.

Comment: Btw utils class as shown here is useless and only complicated the code with absolutely no benefit

Comment: I think that code shouldn't never compilled. First parameter in`Toast.makeText` is Context, no Application, no Activity. You can try to use `Utils.getApp().getApplicationContext()`, but better way is to use context from place where you'll call that function eg. activity, service, broadcastreceiver.

Comment: @grabarz121 Sorry, but I may not understand what you mean. Could you please explain it in details?

Answer (score 0):

```
Toast.makeText(Utils.getApp().....
```

The first parameter should be filled with activity

Comment: Well, according to the doc: @param context The context to use.  Usually your {@link android.app.Application}
or {@link android.app.Activity} object.

Comment: Therefore, the `Context` param can be `Application` object.

Comment: I think you should use activity context. Context is not only one type....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128589/difference-between-activity-context-and-application-context

Answer (score 0):

how about put context in parameter?

```
public static void showToast(Context context, @StringRes int messageId) {
    if (toast == null) {
        toast = Toast.makeText(context, messageId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
    toast.setText(messageId);
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}
```

in activity :

```
showToast(this, R.string.toast)
```