# What type of context should I use in this case and why?

Tags: java, android, android-context

I am using the following function in one of my activities of my app:

```
public static float convertDpToPixel(float dp, Context context){
    return dp * ((float) context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
}
```

What context should I use?

**Application Context**: tied to the Lifecycle of an Application

**Activity Context**: tied to the life cycle of activity

**Base Context**: the base context as set by the constructor or setBaseContext

I have done it like this and it seems to work:

In my_activity.java:

```
float conversion = convertDpToPixel(10, this);
```

But also I could do the following:

```
float conversion = convertDpToPixel(10, getApplicationContext());
```

And also the following:

```
float conversion = convertDpToPixel(10, getBaseContext());
```

I think that in this specific case it doesn't really matter as it will get the resources of the app and it is included in all the contextes types but I would like to ensure what I am saying. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

All of three you can use in this case.
Context usually use to get resource or launch some system service, and I found a context explain in this website https://www.jianshu.com/p/94e0f9ab3f1d, here is the picture he explain when each context can be use:
(不推荐 mean not recommended)
[image]

Most of case you can use Application, Activity, and Service context, but beside some scene, like show dialog,start activity, and layout inflation.
A dialog need to build base on a activity, so you can't use other two type context.
This case seems to be load resource values, so you can use all of three.

Other information about context: [Difference between Activity Context and Application Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128589/difference-between-activity-context-and-application-context), https://web.archive.org/web/20150329210012/https://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/.

Comment: You should not use the Application context to load resource values, as the resource set may be different in the Activity context.  For example, an Activity may have a theme that alters it.  It will work (it won't crash), but it may not be right.

Comment: @GabeSechan  according to your answer I think I should use this one: float conversion = convertDpToPixel(10, this); Is that right?