# Toast message not displaying when I click on the button

Tags: android, kotlin

I am creating a simple app on which when the button is clicked a toast message is displaying. But when the button is clicked the toast message does not display.

This is my mainActivity and activityMain.xml code.

```
package com.example.myapplication2

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val clickMeButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.toast_button)

        clickMeButton.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Toast Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/toast_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click Me!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use activity context but you are using appcontext (see [Difference between Activity Context and Application Context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4128589)). You should update code with this:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Toast Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```