# context is getting exception in android 2.1

Tags: android, exception

I use android 2.2 for developing my application. But when I run it on 2.1 emulator, it caught ome exception.

Every exception is caught on 'Context'. Actaully I am using ActivityGroup in my application. And my activity is extending another class. So i use 'this.getParent()' in the field of 'Context'. This is working fine in android 2.2 and also on later version. I use getBaseConext() and getApplicationContext(). But the error is still remains there. The dialog is coming. But then suddently it caught exception.

For example :

```
 Dialog dateDialog = new Dialog(this.getParent());
```

But in android 2.1 , it caught Exception: WindowManager$BadTockenException .

How can I specify 'context' in android 2.1 ?

Thank you....

Comment: what about another apis (1.5, 1.6)?
I think, it is / was a bug by Dialogs. Tried new Dialog(this)?

Comment: 'this' will not work. Bcause i am using ActivityGroup

Answer (score 1):

Both [`ActivityGroup`](http://d.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html) and [`Activity`](http://d.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) are [`Context`](http://d.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)s, and I'll bet you the `Activity` inherits the `ActivityGroup`'s `Context` by default. In conclusion, try using `this`.

What you have described is very similar to [a problem I had](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561803/android-progressdialog-show-crashes-with-getapplicationcontext), which seemed to be a problem with launching dialogs from `onCreate` and using anything other than `this` as a `Context`.

Answer (score 0):

your activity group has activities in it, doesn't it?

what if you declare in each of inner activities context member (**mContext**) and initialize it with **this** in **onCreate()**? then you can call **new Dialog(mContext)**

UPD:
i googled a bit because this problem could be interesting for me as well. And i've found this Link:

http://www.codingon24s.com/2011/02/dialogs-and-android-view-windowmanagerbadtokenexception-2/

But i haven't tried it

Comment: I tried what u suggested. But stiil getting the error : "android.view.WindowManager$BadTockenException : unable to add window -- token null is not for an application."

Comment: Have you seen this link http://www.codingon24s.com/2011/02/dialogs-and-android-view-windowmanagerbadtokenexception-2/ ?