# How to create android Dialog with 2 SingleChoiceItems?

Tags: android, dialog, android-listview

I.e. user should be able to choose values from 2 lists (4 options in each).
Ideally it should look like drop down lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need two `Spinners` in a `Dialog`. OK, wrap spinners with a `LinearLayout` and use `Dialog.setContentView(View)` to embed the `LinearLayout` into the dialog.

The [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog) on this.

Comment: Trying to do so and getting error _android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application_, the following code is used: `dialog = new Dialog(getApplicationContext());
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_subscription);
dialog.setTitle("Dialog");
Spinner subQ = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.sub_q);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapQ = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.sub_q_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapQ.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
subQ.setAdapter(adapQ);

Comment: @LA_: Your code looks OK. Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561803/android-progressdialog-show-crashes-with-getapplicationcontext

Comment: Thanks, I've changed `getApplicationContext` to `this` and it started to work.