# Why does my alert dialog crash

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

recently I followed a tutorial on how to create an alert dialog and when i click on delete button, it should show me an alert before deleting but it crashed instead. Can someone tell me where my error lies?

Below is my code:

```
// Delete button click event
    btnDeleteEvent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // alerting user before deleting event
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    getApplicationContext());
            // set title
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Warning!");
            // set dialog message
            alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage("Are you sure to delete event?")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {
                                    // if yes, deleting event in background
                                    // thread
                                    new DeleteEvent().execute();
                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton("No",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {
                                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Here is my logcat:

```
08-18 02:02:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1288): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-18 02:02:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1288): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
08-18 02:02:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:509)
08-18 02:02:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
08-18 02:02:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
08-18 02:02:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
08-18 02:02:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at com.stts.sparetimetradingsystem.employer.EditEventActivity$5.onClick(EditEventActivity.java:270)
08-18 02:02:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
08-18 02:02:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
08-18 02:02:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-18 02:02:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-18 02:02:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-18 02:02:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-18 02:02:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-18 02:02:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-18 02:02:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-18 02:02:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-18 02:02:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the Activity's context instead of the application context

Comment: He's right and to be more precise AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ouractivity.this);

Comment: umm, shouldn't it be yourActivity.this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use dialog.dismiss() and even change getApplication context to YourActivity.this

You can refer to http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2012/07/alert-box-code.html

Answer (score 0):

According to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796611/dialog-throwing-unable-to-add-window-token-null-is-not-for-an-application-wi), you should use `this` instead of `getApplicationContext()` inside the constructor.

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // alerting user before deleting event
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```