# Dialog Crashes App onClick

Tags: java, android, android-dialog

I am trying to display a dialog in the onClick method of a TextView. I tested the onClick without the dialog box using a log and it works. When I add the dialogbox to it, like this:

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
            Dialog d = new Dialog(context);
            d.setTitle("Test");
            TextView testField = new TextView(context);
            testField.setText("Success!");
            d.setContentView(testField);
            d.show();
```

This is all in a textView's onClick method. The exception I get says unable to add window -- token null is not for an application.

Can someone please explain to me why this isn't working. I have tons of questions here about getting exceptions in android and the answer always  has to do with the order of the code. Is there a reference somewhere about how code should be ordered?!

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried reading logcat?

Comment: Intead of  Dialog d = new Dialog(context); try like Dialog d = new Dialog(YourActivity.this);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are creating Dialog in onClick() always use

```
void onClick(View v)
{
    Dialog d = new Dialog(v.getContext());
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    TextView testField = new TextView(v.context);
    testField.setText("Success!");
    d.setContentView(testField);
    d.show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! Can you please explain to me what exactly a context is. I looked at it in the documentation but I still don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Dialog d = new Dialog(context);`

use `Dialog d = new Dialog(this);`

context obtained from `getApplicationContext();` should not be used for dialogs.

For more info, refer question:

[Dialog throwing "Unable to add window — token null is not for an application” with getApplication() as context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5796611/1369222)