# How to create a android alertdialog in phonestatelistener?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, builder

The code looks like this:

1) Declare the new activity in manifest file.
(AndroidManifest.xml):

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ConfirmDialog"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="vertical">          
    </activity>
```

2) Create new class extends activity.
(public class ConfirmDialog extends Activity)

```
private static final int DIALOG_YES_NO_MESSAGE = 1;

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_YES_NO_MESSAGE:
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(ConfirmDialog.this)
            .setIconAttribute(android.R.attr.alertDialogIcon)
            .setTitle(R.string.app_name)
            .setMessage(R.string.ask_confirm)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.ask_confirm_yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    finish();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.ask_confirm_no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    finish();
                }
            })
            .create();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    showDialog(DIALOG_YES_NO_MESSAGE);
}
```

3) Use the new created activity in phonestatelistener. 
(public class Listener extends PhoneStateListener)

```
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber){

    switch(state){              
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            confirmCall();          
        break;
    }

    super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);

}   

private void confirmCall(){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example", "com.example.ConfirmDialog"));
    mContext.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: And what is the error log output?

Comment: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Comment: `mContext` is probably null. It's impossible to tell without the full log and code.

Comment: mContext is not null, because the code Toast.makeText(mContext, "error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); in exception of try works fine!

Comment: The `Context` that you're using may not be valid for doing window operations, such as making dialogs. See the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796611/dialog-throwing-unable-to-add-window-token-null-is-not-for-an-application-wi) for some suggestions. As Eric said, we need to see the code.

Comment: try using `mContext.getApplicationContext()` instead of just mContext

Comment: @Ludiaz We need to see where `mContext` is being initialized.

Comment: @acj the mContext is initilized, because Toast works. Anyway, mContext is a wore the getApplicationContext(), stored in a Config class. This Config class received context of a SherlockFragmentActivity. I have altered the activity of this config.setContext (getApplicationContext) for config.setContext (this). Now is working. The problem is that there is still exactly what I wanted, because I have to open my app to user wiew the alert. I wanted this alert "exploded" on the screen without opening the app.

Comment: @acj the app crashes and freezes the android. after a while it reboots. sometimes I have to remove the battery. I noticed that if I take the lines that call the activity of the dialog (in confirmCall ()), the app works normally.

Comment: @Ludiaz You're starting an activity in your own app, so you can use the simpler form `new Intent(this, ConfirmDialog.class)`. Also, be sure that `ConfirmDialog` is declared in the manifest.

Comment: i'm trying this, but eclipse show error "the constructor intent is undefined and show has solution "remove arguments".

Answer (score 0):

Not all `Context` objects are equal, and reusing them is dangerous because it can result in the error that you're seeing. Per your comment, your revised code is storing a `Context` from SherlockFragmentActivity in your `Config` class, and then using it later when that `Activity` (and the window that it was using) may not exist anymore. The `Context` isn't null and can probably be used to do a `Toast`, but doing windowing operations is very risky.

One solution is to create a dialog-themed activity in your app that will only show the dialog. In `confirmCall()`, launch your activity with `startActivity()`, and then let the activity create the dialog. To the user, a dialog will appear on the screen without an app running, but in fact your app *is* running and can respond to the user's Yes/No choice on the dialog. Be sure to use

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
```

so that the dialog's `Context` is an `Activity`.