# Dialogfragment(Alert-Dialog) is crashing when I am trying to open it for the second time on Button Click

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment

Dialogfragment is crashing when i am trying to open it second time on button click.This Dialogfragment shows existing mail accounts in single select radio buttons. Here is my code :

```
public String[] allemails() {
    _accountMgr = AccountManager.get(getActivity());
    Account[] accounts = _accountMgr.getAccounts();
    numberOfEmail = accounts.length;
    String[] emailAddress = new String[numberOfEmail];

    for (Account account : accounts) {
        accountsList = account.name.toString();
        emailAddress[r] = accountsList;
        r += 1;
    }
    MyAlertDialog f = new MyAlertDialog();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putStringArray("Title", emailAddress);
    f.setArguments(args);

    return emailAddress;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FFFF'>"
            + "Choose Account" + "</font>"));

    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_udinic);
    builder.setCancelable(false).setSingleChoiceItems(allemails(), -1,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = (AlertDialog) dialog;
                    alertDialog.getButton(-1).setEnabled(true);

                }
            });
    builder.setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Set",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(id).setVisibility(
                            View.INVISIBLE);

                    ListView lw = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView();
                    CharSequence checkedItem = (CharSequence) lw
                            .getAdapter().getItem(
                                    lw.getCheckedItemPosition());

                    // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), checkedItem,
                    // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    ((Main) getActivity()).doPositiveClick(checkedItem);
                    // dialog.dismiss();
                    // getDialog().dismiss();

                }
            });

    builder.setCancelable(false).setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // User cancelled the dialog

                    // Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    // "You Press Cancel Button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    // dialog.dismiss();

                }

            });

    dialog = builder.create();
    return dialog;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    dialog.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    // Removes the dismiss message to avoid shown dialogs being dismissed.
    if (getDialog() != null && getRetainInstance())
        getDialog().setDismissMessage(null);

    super.onDestroyView();
}
```

Here is my Logcat :

```
    02-19 05:34:06.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1808): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    02-19 05:34:06.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1808): Process: com.udinic.accounts_authenticator_example, PID: 1808
    02-19 05:34:06.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1808): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
    02-19 05:34:06.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1808):     at com.mycuratio.app.MyAlertDialog.allemails(MyAlertDialog.java:46)
    02-19 05:34:06.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1808):     at com.mycuratio.app.MyAlertDialog.onCreateDialog(MyAlertDialog.java:70)
    02-19 05:34:06.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1808):     at android.app.DialogFragment.getLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:398)
    02-19 05:34:06.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1808):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
    02-19 05:34:06.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1808):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
    02-19 05:34:06.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1808):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
    02-19 05:34:06.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1808):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
    02-19 05:34:06.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1808):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
    02-19 05:34:06.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1808):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    02-19 05:34:06.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1808):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    02-19 05:34:06.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1808):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    02-19 05:34:06.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1808):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    02-19 05:34:06.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1808):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    02-19 05:34:06.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1808):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    02-19 05:34:06.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1808):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    02-19 05:34:06.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1808):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    02-19 05:34:06.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1808):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: and why you are calling `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` in `onCreateDialog()`?

Comment: @GopalRao : If i remove this code ..same thing happening

Comment: consider kalyan pvs's comment...

Comment: try to post the root Exception...

Comment: @kalyanpvs I post logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before `for` loop, reset the value of `r` to zero.

```
r = 0;
for (Account account : accounts) {
    accountsList = account.name.toString();
    emailAddress[r] = accountsList;
    r += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe **unable to add window token null** is the error you are receiving. And as @Gopal said probable reason is that you are calling,

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

or there are chances that you are mistakenly leaking out the reference to the activity somewhere.

Please see the below link for more details on this.
[Dialog throwing "Unable to add window — token null is not for an application” with getApplication() as context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796611/dialog-throwing-unable-to-add-window-token-null-is-not-for-an-application-wi)

Pardon me if this is not the case.