# Why does ad.show() fail?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have this method in which i want to create an AlertDialog but when I call it the application stops working when it reaches ad.show

```
public void showSettingsAlert() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is necessary for Traffic Finder");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            //mContext.startActivity(intent);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Create Alert Dialog
    AlertDialog ad= alertDialog.create();

    // Showing Alert Message
    ad.show();
}
```

I get this:

```
08-26 20:47:11.462  28940-29005/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[CoordinatesService]
Process: com.example.manos.trafficfinder, PID: 28940
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:566)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:282)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
        at com.example.manos.trafficfinder.GPSTracker.showSettingsAlert(GPSTracker.java:182)
        at com.example.manos.trafficfinder.GeographicCoordinates.getLatitudeString(GeographicCoordinates.java:32)
        at com.example.manos.trafficfinder.DataManagement.addPosition(DataManagement.java:116)
        at com.example.manos.trafficfinder.CoordinatesService.onHandleIntent(CoordinatesService.java:28)
        at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: Please post your stack trace. (logcat)

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Duplicate:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796611/dialog-throwing-unable-to-add-window-token-null-is-not-for-an-application-wi

Answer (score 1):

The `Context` passed to `AlertDialog.Builder` seems incorrect. Try `YourClass.this` instead of `mContext`.

Comment: I changed it to this:
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(GPSTracker.this);

Now the code fails at this line