# You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme on AlertDialog creation

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-appcompat, appcompatactivity

My MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
               ....
               ...
}
```

Style.xml:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

</resources>
```

When i run the app then it is working perfect but when i am trying to create/show `AlertDialog.Builder` from my adapter class then it gives error

```
 `You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:124)`
```

Manifest file:

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

AlertDialog code:

```
public class mainviewAdapter  extends ArrayAdapter<MainCategory>
{

 AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle;
 public mainviewAdapter  (Context context, ArrayList<MainCategory> values) {
        super(context, R.layout.home_rt, values);

        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
        builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builderSingle.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        builderSingle.setTitle("Select Your Category");


    }

   on button click:

   builderSingle.setNegativeButton("cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

        builderSingle.setAdapter(arrayAdapter,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    }
                });

        builderSingle.show();
```

How can i solved this error on `Alertdialog` ?

Comment: share code of AlertDialog.Builder to know issue

Comment: @kapilrajput have added code for alertdialog

Answer (score 1):

Try to set Theme to your AlertDialog by replacing your line of code :

```
builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
```

with :

```
builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(context,R.style.dialogTheme);
```

Add code in your style.xml 
:

```
<style name="dialogTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
<!-- Any customizations for your app running on devices with Theme.Holo here -->
</style>
```

and remember one thing to avoid `Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application` Exception Instead of `getApplicationContext()`, just use `Activityname.this`

Comment: After try this code i am getting `Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:641)` error.

Comment: I have edit my Answer try it now it will work and use Activityname.this as context while creating object of your class MainviewAdapter

Comment: It's because you are using the wrong context, try with ActivityName.this see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7229248/2324122)