# Android progress dialog while waiting to dialog show up

Tags: android, multithreading, dialog, onclick, progressdialog

In my android application, dialog's showing up takes a time. At that time I want to show progress dialog. I learned that the progress dialog should be executed in thread but when I use a thread it gives an error.

I created progress dialog in oncreate method and tried to show in my button's onclick method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context = getApplicationContext();

    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context, R.style.StyledDialog);
    mProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    Drawable drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progress_dialog);
    mProgressDialog.setProgressDrawable(drawable);
}
```

Following code is my button's onclick method which is defined in xml file like :           `android:onClick="refList"`

```
public void refList(View v) {


    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            mProgressDialog.show();

        }
    });
    t.start();

    if(!refListDialog.isShowing()) {
        refListDialog.show();
        t.interrupt();

    }

}
```

This is the exception:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-27305 java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
        at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:3052)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:3321)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:294)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:226)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:151)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
        at gcm.b4deploy.com.hesapozeti.MainActivity$2.run(MainActivity.java:196)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I am really stuck and waiting ideas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i dont know where you heard this but progress dialogs should def not be called in a thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't get the idea why you put the progressDialog inside a thread.

```
yourProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);
yourProgress.setTitle("Title");
yourProgress.setMessage("wait for a while"); yourProgress.getProcess();
yourProgress.show();
```

Put this code first in your function in the onClick method. It will execute sequentially.And you can make conditional statement, and if done, call yourProgress.dismiss();

[image: sample code] - add your statement above the progressDialog.setTitle. I suggest you declare the progress dialog outside this method, so that you can dismiss that one in the other method which return true. Just remove those runnable thing.

Comment: When I did as your said it gives an error: FATAL EXCEPTION: main     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener...

Comment: If (statement) { yourProgressDialog... Then your statement }else{}

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that I used getApplicationContext() instead of MainActivity.this. No need to use thread.

Comment: Do you remove the runnable? The thread you just created? getApplicationContext() is suitable for fragments. In activity user the CLASS_NAME.this . (Glad to help even though it lack more instruction)

Comment: I have already remove it. But it was still getting an error. Then I create onclick method like yours (not defined in xml by defining .setOnClickListener()....) then the error is changed. Then I googled that error and used again stackoverflow (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796611/dialog-throwing-unable-to-add-window-token-null-is-not-for-an-application-wi) then it solved. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        mProgressDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Still getting error: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener..