# I want to open dialog box when i click on ImageView in Recyclerview

Tags: android

I want to open dialog box when i click on ImageView in Recyclerview.

**When i show Toast it's working(Showing) but when i want to show
   AlertDialog Box it's not working (on image click application crash) Please solve it.
   This is my Adapter Class:-**

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<GetterSetter> arrayList;
private Context context;

public  RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<GetterSetter> arrayList, Context context){
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
    this.context = context;
}
@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.detail,viewGroup,false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, final int i) {
    GetterSetter fp = arrayList.get(i);
    myViewHolder.nametxt.setText(fp.getEmpname());
    myViewHolder.companytxt.setText(fp.getCompanyname());
    myViewHolder.proImg.setImageResource(fp.getEmppic());
    myViewHolder.callImg.setImageResource(fp.callpic);
    myViewHolder.msgimg.setImageResource(fp.msgpic);


    myViewHolder.callImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.design);
            dialog.setTitle("Dialog Box");
            TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
            text.setText("Android custom dialog example!");
            Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.okbtn);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView proImg,callImg,msgimg;
    TextView nametxt,companytxt;
    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(null);
        proImg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        callImg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.smallimage1);
        msgimg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.smallimage2);
        nametxt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        companytxt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.company);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: what is your error? post your log

Comment: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an applicationat com.example.hp.myapplication.RecyclerAdapter$1.onClick(RecyclerAdapter.java:65)

Comment: check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796611/dialog-throwing-unable-to-add-window-token-null-is-not-for-an-application-wi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code..

make interface into adapter class for click event handleing..

```
    OnItemClick onItemClick;

public void setOnItemClick(OnItemClick onItemClick) {
    this.onItemClick = onItemClick;
}

public interface OnItemClick {
    void getPosition(); //pass any things
}
```

after that..

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    // below code handle click event on recycler view item.
    String data = mStringList.get(position);
    holder.textView.setText(data);
    holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onItemClick.getPosition();
        }
    });
}
```

after that make dialog code into one method and define into activity ..

```
private void showDialog(){
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.design);
    dialog.setTitle("Dialog Box");
    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
    text.setText("Android custom dialog example!");
    Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.okbtn);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
```

after that bind adapter into recyclerview or listview it means adapter not null then call below code..

```
      adpater.setOnItemClick(new RecyclerViewAdpater.OnItemClick() {
        @Override
        public void getPosition() {
            showDialog();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank You So much Android Team, It's working.

Comment: then pl accept the answer.