# Show Progress Dialog between threads?

Tags: android

Show Progress Dialog between threads?

Comment: could you also post the crash log?

Comment: are you ensuring to terminate the previous asynctask when your activity is paused?

Comment: are you using a tahhost inside a tabhost (or some kind of activity group) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid using the `getApplicationContext()`-method to get a `Context`-object. There are better ways:

- If in an Activity, you can simply supply `this`
- If in an inner-class of an Activity, you can supply `OuterClassName.this`
- When in a Helper-class which needs a `Context`-object to create e.g. a View, supply a `Context`-Object via the constructor and save it in a property.

Also see this similar question: [Android: ProgressDialog.show() crashes with getApplicationContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561803/android-progressdialog-show-crashes-with-getapplicationcontext)