# crash android app

Tags: android, multithreading, android-alertdialog

I am debugging a multithreading android app with many activities. In one activity I need to show an AlertDialog. I don't know if this activity is active or not. What should I write in the Builder method of AlertDialog? I have written the following:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext())
```

but my app crashes after this.

UPDATE:
crashes and says

```
01-02 21:49:13.210: E/AndroidRuntime(23940): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

Comment: crashes and says WHAT? And why haven't you put here the line on which it is crushing?

Comment: You're going to have to post more of your code and paste the output from the log cat that happens when your application crashes.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561803/android-progressdialog-show-crashes-with-getapplicationcontext

Answer (score 1):

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this)
```