# How do I display a dialog in android without an Activity context?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

This seems like it should be simple, but I'm not finding an answer anywhere.  I have an Android application that performs network tasks in the background.  If an error comes back, I want to display an error dialog.  When the task returns, I don't know which Activity is in the foreground.  Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561803/android-progressdialog-show-crashes-with-getapplicationcontext), it looks like we can't use the application context to display a dialog (and indeed I do get the crash if I try).

So how can I get the context of the current activity?  Again, the receiver for the network task is running in the Application context, not in a particular Activity.  Any other ideas?

Edit: I should clarify.  I don't want to display an error dialog if I'm not the foreground application.  I'm only interested in the case where our app is in the foreground for now.

Comment: You could use a [Toast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html). Afaik there is no way to display a Dialog w/o being the active foreground app.

Comment: Possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11324877/5764479

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> If an error comes back, I want to display an error dialog.

Please only do this if you know that the user is actively using your application. The user will be very very annoyed if you interrupt them in the middle of something else (playing a game, watching a movie, reading a book).

> So how can I get the context of the current activity?

You don't. At most, you let the current activity know that it needs to do something.

> Any other ideas?

One possibility is to use an ordered broadcast, so *if* you have a foreground activity, it gets control, otherwise you raise a `Notification` to let the user know about the problem without popping a dialog. The activity that receives the ordered broadcast can display an `AlertDialog` or otherwise let the user know about the problem. I wrote about the details of how to do this [in a blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/08/11/activity-notification-ordered-broadcast.html) (and [a book chapter](http://commonsware.com/AdvAndroid), for that matter), and [here is a sample application](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Broadcast/Ordered) demonstrating the technique.

Or, have the service call `startActivity()` to start up [a dialog-themed activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyATheme).

Comment: If he has no context, how can he create & fire a notification? Afaik a notification requires a context to be created? I am having a background thread running that is not bound to any activity - hence I have no way to get hold of an activity context to start the notification in the first place.

Comment: @Zainodis: "I am having a background thread running that is not bound to any activity" -- that is a bug. You should have it be managed by some component, such as a service. Then, the `Service` is your `Context` for following what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the hint - we used to have a service for it (the background thread handles server connections) - then we reverted to a background thread, because occasionally our service would get killed (by the os we assumed, since there were no exception or the like to cause abrupt failure) for no apparent reason (which is a no-go in our case).

Answer (score 8):

While this question is quite old, meanwhile there is a nice solution if you want it to work with any active `Activity`. So you wouldn't need to register individual `Activities` like it's proposed in other answers.

I want to emphasize that this is usually something that you should try to avoid - creating dialogs w/o knowing the view context, but there might be special circumstances where this can be useful.

With this solution using `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` you're always aware of the active `Activity` on `Application` level. You can then use this active `Activity` to open dialogs or other `Activities` from e.g. network code where you would only have access to the `Application` class:

```
class YourApplication : Application() {

    private val activeActivityCallbacks = ActiveActivityLifecycleCallbacks()

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(activeActivityCallbacks)
    }

    override fun onTerminate() {
       unregisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(activeActivityCallbacks)
       super.onTerminate()
    }

    fun getActiveActivity(): Activity? = activeActivityCallbacks.getActiveActivity()
// ...
}


class ActiveActivityLifecycleCallbacks : Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

   private var activeActivity: Activity? = null

   fun getActiveActivity(): Activity? = activeActivity

   override fun onActivityCreated(activity: Activity, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      activeActivity = activity
   }

   override fun onActivityDestroyed(activity: Activity) {
      if (activity === activeActivity) {
         activeActivity = null
      }
   }
// ...
}
```

From anywhere:

```
YourApplication.get().getActiveActivity()?.let { activity ->
    activity.runOnUiThread {
       AlertDialog.Builder(activity).setMessage("test").show()
    }
}
```

Please check other SO posts how to implement a getter for the `Application`: e.g. [Kotlin singleton application class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37391221/kotlin-singleton-application-class)

Answer (score 6):

I've created a helper class that implements CommonsWare's idea.  Activities that wish to display alerts just need to call Alerts.register() and Alerts.unregister().  Then anyone can call Alerts.displayError().

Comments welcome.

```
public class Alerts {

    private static class AlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        private static HashMap<Activity, AlertReceiver> registrations;
        private Context activityContext;

        static {
            registrations = new HashMap<Activity, AlertReceiver>();
        }

        static void register(Activity activity) {
            AlertReceiver receiver = new AlertReceiver(activity);
            activity.registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(MyApplication.INTENT_DISPLAYERROR));
            registrations.put(activity, receiver);
        }

        static void unregister(Activity activity) {
            AlertReceiver receiver = registrations.get(activity);
            if(receiver != null) {
                activity.unregisterReceiver(receiver);
                registrations.remove(activity);
            }
        }

        private AlertReceiver(Activity activity) {
            activityContext = activity;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            abortBroadcast();
            String msg = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
            displayErrorInternal(activityContext, msg);
        }
    }

    public static void register(Activity activity) {
        AlertReceiver.register(activity);
    }

    public static void unregister(Activity activity) {
        AlertReceiver.unregister(activity);
    }

    public static void displayError(Context context, String msg) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MyApplication.INTENT_DISPLAYERROR);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msg);
        context.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null);
    }

    private static void displayErrorInternal(Context context, String msg) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle("Error")
               .setMessage(msg)
               .setCancelable(false)
               .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       dialog.cancel();
                   }
               });
        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

        alert.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: MyApplication.INTENT_DISPLAYERROR is a constant on, what I'm assuming is, ManicBlowfish's app that represents a String. You could replace that with a String of your choosing.

Comment: I'd advise against this solution.  It's keeping static references to Activities which is one of the biggest causes of memory leaks in Android.  It is fine if they are registered/unregistered.  Lint will probably fail due to this as well.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using custom created Dialog. It will be called by Service or Handler even in the case if the current Activity will lose focus.

**Activity of my custom Dialog**:

```
public class AlertDialogue extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnOk;
    TextView textDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //comment this line if you need to show Title.
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alert_dialogue);

        textDialog = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_dialog) ;
        textDialog.setText("Hello, I'm the dialog text!");

        btnOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_dialog);
        btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You can call this dialog using:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlertDialogue.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

**In the Manifest**:

```
<activity android:name=".AlertDialogue"
    android:theme="@style/AlertDialogMy">

</activity>
```

**style:**

```
<resources>

    <style name="AlertDialogMy" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item> //delete this line if you need to show Title.
    </style>

</resources>
```

---

Here is the full code of this [example](https://github.com/vmarch/CustomDialog).

Comment: that's not the solution if you want to finish this activity from outside activity

Answer (score 2):

Why don't use event bus (https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) ?

1. Define events:

   ```
   public class ShowErrorMessageEvent {

       public String errorMessage;

       public ShowErrorMessageEvent(String errorMessage) {
           this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
       }
       public String getErrorMessage() {
           return this.errorMessage;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Prepare subscribers for all activities you needed:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onStart() { 
       super.onStart(); 
       EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void onStop() {
       EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
       super.onStop();
   }
   ```
3. In all activities, show the dialog if the event received

   ```
    public void onEvent(ShowErrorMessageEvent event) {
        /* Show dialog with event.getErrorMessage() from background thread */
    };
   ```
4. In your background thread, post the error event:

   ```
   EventBus.getDefault().post(new ShowErrorMessageEvent("This is an error message!"));
   ```

Answer (score 0):

What type of network tasks are going on in the background.  I would suggest possibly rethinking the design. Perhaps a notification would be better? Or maybe a "results summary" screen. As a user I Would rather a non obtrusive signal of error if I am not actively waiting for the task to complete.

Answer (score 0):

I also face the problem. I find out a simple and effective solution. Usuallay, we have a base activity used to handle some common logic. So have this:

```
public class BaseActionBarActivity extends ActionBarActivity{  //this BaseActionBarActivity is the Base Act

   private static BaseActionBarActivity current;

   @Override
   protected void onStart() {
     super.onStart();
     current=this;
   }


   public static BaseActionBarActivity getCurrentContext() {
     return current;
   }
}
```

current field is the current Context Actitvity. And I believe there is not memory leak question.  It works well for me!  Hope helpful

Comment: Don't make context static

Answer (score 0):

you need to reset type of Window which dialog attached, as follow: 
dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);

do not forget declaring "android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" permission in your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation that will allow an AlertDialog to be displayed on top of the current active activity (this is an example of a message dialog, but can be used for alerts as well).

```
public class AlertsDialogue
{
    private AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder;
    private AlertDialog alert;

    public AlertsDialogue(Context context, String title, String message)
    {
        alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(title);
        alertDialogBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(message)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton(context.getString(R.string.text_ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {
                    alert.dismiss();
                }
            });

        alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        Window window = alert.getWindow();
        if (window != null)
        {
            // the important stuff..
            window.setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST);
            alert.show();
        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

The dialog will be displayed even if the context on which it was instantiated with is no longer active, much like `Toast`.

Call with `new AlertsDialogue(MyActivity.this, "title", "message");`

No additional permissions are required in the AndroidManifest file.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is to show dialogs and other view related work in Activity / Fragment, not in some other class that has no idea what context is.

But there are some valid reasons to want to do that outside of Views. For example, I want to show some alert dialog to help testing the app in mock build.  To provide activity context you can do several things, I will write about two:

1. Inject activity context with scope tied to activity. It is the best solution, but requires to have architecture that is correctly implemented, with scoping in mind. I will not describe how to do it here, it can be found in tutorials.
2. I have created some helper class with activity's extention to get context from activity. It doesn't store context, but function that can provide context, so I think it shouldn't cause memory leaks (? not tested, it is for mocked builds for testers, so didn't spend much time checking that)

   ```
   object ActivityContextProviderForMockBuilds {

       private val contextProvider = MutableSharedFlow<(Context) -> Unit>(extraBufferCapacity = 1)

       fun getContext(contextCallback: (Context) -> Unit) = contextProvider.tryEmit(contextCallback)

       fun AppCompatActivity.setContextProviderForMockBuild() {
           if (BuildConfig.MOCKS_ENABLED) {
               contextProvider.onEach {
                   it.invoke(this)
               }.launchIn(lifecycleScope)
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Usage:

```
ActivityContextProviderForMockBuilds.getContext { context -> ... }
```

But as said previously, you shouldn't use activity context outside of views in most cases and if yes, then by dependency injection :)

Answer (score -4):

Well, I think that the best for you would be an AsyncTask. Here an example and doc:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html