# Display custom exception error popup

Tags: java, exception, android, uncaughtexceptionhandler

I created a custom exception handler in a class extending Application, using `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler`, to print uncaught exceptions' stack traces to a file.  I'd like it to also display a custom error popup to the user, rather than the default "Unfortunately, [application] has stopped" message.

The following method creates an AlertDialog which returns to the main menu when clicked.  It can be run even on background threads.

```
void alert(final String msg) {
    final Activity activity = (Activity) getContext();
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setMessage(msg)
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, MainMenu.class));
                }
            })
            .show();
        }
    });
}
```

However, the AlertDialog requires that the current activity be known.  To use this method with an exception handler, I could keep a pointer to the current activity in the Application class, which is reset in each Activity's `onResume()` method, but I'm concerned about leaking memory.

What is a preferable way to bring up an AlertDialog when an uncaught exception is thrown?

Comment: If you're thinking along the lines of replacing the default ANR screen - no.

Comment: i think this is relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751088/how-do-i-display-a-dialog-in-android-without-an-activity-context

Comment: @chancea Thanks for the link, but these solutions seem to require a background Service as the context, instead of an Activity.

Comment: @Shark This isn't the Application Not Responding screen, it's the screen that occurs when there's an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the *default* error popup, handle the exception and then execute the default uncaught exception handler:

```
final Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultHandler = 
    Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        doCustomHandlingHere();
        defaultHandler.uncaughtException(t,e);
    }
});
```

To get a custom error popup, I believe you would have to set the default uncaught exception handler for each activity separately.  See [this post](https://web.archive.org/web/20161019112503/http://www.codeovertones.com:80/2009/09/crash-report-for-android-app.html) for details.

Comment: The link is not opening? how to add custom dialog?