# Is there a way to open a dialog adfet an activity ended?

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

Is there a way to open a dialog after an activity ended? If i try to open it, i get the error:

> activity has leaked window that was originally added here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dialog needs an Activity, so this is expected behaviour. I think this links to a possible workaround: [How do I display a dialog in android without an Activity context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751088/how-do-i-display-a-dialog-in-android-without-an-activity-context)