# Display dialog box before intent activity starts in android

Tags: android, dialog, android-edittext, toast

I'm creating an application in which I've to display a dialog box. This dialog box having an edittext and a button. I want to display this dialog box before activity starts. please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an instance of dialog in onCreate(); and show it in onResume();

Answer (score 0):

you can use a dialog fragment:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

this is an example of how to use it:

[check out this tutorial](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html)

Answer (score 0):

there are some ways where what you can do is  you can have a activity which is registered as

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

at manifest and show the activity before yours activity that it will be an appearance of dialog beside this

visit

[How do I display a dialog in android without an Activity context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751088/how-do-i-display-a-dialog-in-android-without-an-activity-context)