# Kotlin singleton application class

Tags: android, singleton, kotlin

On Android I want to make my application class a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Making it like this:

```
object MyApplication: Application(){}
```

won't work. The following error is thrown at runtime:

> java.lang.IllegalAccessException: private com....is not accessible from class android.app.Instrumentation.

Doing this is also not possible:

```
class MyApp: Application() {

    private val instance_: MyApp

    init{
        instance_ = this
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree());
        }
    }

    companion object{
        fun getInstance() = instance_
    }
}
```

How can I get an instance of my application class everywhere in my app? I would like to use `MyApp.instance()` instead of `(applicationContext as MyApp)`.

Also an explanation why I want this: I have classes in my app. For example, a SharedPreference Singleton which is initialised with a context, and as it’s a singleton, it can't have arguments.

Comment: please don't access the context statically, it's very bad and it could create problems later on. Instead context in Android should be accessed [on demand](https://www.fwd.cloud/commit/post/android-context-on-demand/)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you want to **use it to access some static properties** you have there: You will only have one instance of your Application, so simply use the name you gave to the class. Don't worry about it not being an actual singleton, you can use it the same way.

Example:

```
class MyApp : Application() {

    companion object {
        const val CONSTANT = 12
        lateinit var typeface: Typeface
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(assets, "fonts/myFont.ttf")
    }

}
```

Then you can use `MyApp.CONSTANT` and `MyApp.typeface` anywhere in your app.

-

If what you want is **to use it as an application context** you can create an extension property for Context:

```
val Context.myApp: MyApp
        get() = applicationContext as MyApp
```

Then you can use `myApp` to get the the application context anywhere you have a context.

Comment: This looks good @nitrico, but i can't get the ´val Context.myApp: MyApp
        get() = applicationContext as MyApp´ part to work. Could you go into a little more detail? Where this line needs to go and how to access it in another class?

Comment: "get the the application context anywhere you have a context." - Can you explain why if I had a context I would need/want the application context? Seems like if I had a context of any kind, I would likely prefer to use that anyway. The use case where I want the application context is when I don't have a context otherwise, for example, a utility class that accesses a resource string. I'm confused.

Comment: Wasn't it simpler in JAVA?

Comment: Won't this create a new object and now you have two Application objects in memory although you only need one?

Comment: @Mitch "Can you explain why if I had a context I would need/want the application context" The difference is that you can introduce a memory leak to Activity context, if you keep reference of object created using its context when the Activity is no longer needed. If you keep that object (such as image resource) Activity is never GC'd. Application exists during whole app lifespan, so there is no such leak happening. Application context should not be used for task like layout inflation etc. See https://medium.com/@banmarkovic/what-is-context-in-android-and-which-one-should-you-use-e1a8c6529652

Answer (score 122):

You can do the same thing you would do in Java, i.e. put the `Application` instance in a static field. Kotlin doesn't have static fields, but properties in objects are statically accessible.

```
class MyApp: Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        instance = this
    }

    companion object {
        lateinit var instance: MyApp
            private set
    }
}
```

You can then access the property via `MyApp.instance`.

Comment: Whats the use of `private set` at bottom ?

Comment: @Redman because we want only MyApp can set the instance value

Comment: It gives "lateinit property instance has not been initialized" Error

Comment: @ShlomiFresko then you're accessing it before `onCreate` was called.

Comment: Won't this create a new object and now you have two Application objects in memory although you only need one?

Comment: @Shaishav no, you're only assigning the reference to the same object to a property.

Comment: @KirillRakhman one object will be created by the system at app launch and the other object will be due to `companion object`. One may hold reference to other if needed, as above but, both will have to survive as long as the app stays alive. Is this inference incorrect?

Comment: @Shaishav The companion object is of a different type than the outer class, you can look up in the bytecode. You will have one instance of the `MyApp` class and one insance of `MyApp$Companion` holding a reference to the `MyApp` instance. Try it out here: https://pl.kotl.in/Wm_sTSSQo

Comment: @KirillRakhman thanks, the example really helped. Also, the decompiled bytecode showed a different inner class as you suggested.

Comment: How about also including `@Volatile` (before `lateinit`) as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106591/what-is-the-volatile-keyword-useful-for

Comment: The private set is used so that a value can’t be assigned from an external class. @ManoharReddy

Comment: Since it's Kotlin, can't you declare the instance val as a top-level variable?

Comment: @VivekYadav then you can't use `lateinit` modifier. Which means either you have to initialize at declaration (which is not possible here) or you have to declare its type as `MyApp?` which then has to be accessed everywhere as `instance!!` which is quite ugly.

Answer (score 20):

```
class AppController : Application() {

    init {
        instance = this
    }

    companion object {
        private var instance: AppController? = null

        fun applicationContext() : AppController {
            return instance as AppController
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Raja Jawahar this is what I was looking for something concise and the best solution.

Comment: I think this is the best solution. If we put instance = this in onCreate() method, it may cause some problem(ContentProvider may call create before Application's onCreate() method).

Comment: Dear Raja: I have this code as AppController() class that contain a String and I have an activity and a Fragment. inside of fragment I am calling that string from AppController as `AppController.mytext2` but my app crashed and it returned `AppController$Companion.getMytext2(AppControler.kt:11)`. What is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that because Android creates an `Application` instance using its parameterless constructor.

The problem you want to solve can be easily solved with DI. Just create instances with an injector so that the `Context` can be injected into objects as a dependency.

Comment: ya i always knew about that solution but was hoping there was another way. Thanks man

Comment: Can you please clear my doubt? : If context is used as a static variable, then if the dependent class holds its reference, what will not be garbage collected : Application object or the context variable? And if we use DI, then the context is passed to the dependent class, now if that holds the reference, then will the object will be garbage collected? Two chained questions, I hope its clear. Thanks!

Comment: Actually `Application` is `Context` and it won't be gc'ed while the application is running.