# Get shared preferences without context

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences, android-context

Good evening everyone! I want to use shared preferences to store my token(I know that this is not secure, I am new in android development and just want to try) and then pass it to the interceptor. How can I initialize shared preferences there? Thank you! Or can you give me a tips how I can implement interceptor or store token.

Sorry, I already tried to search for this topic, and was not able to implement methods of other developers.

```
object NetworkModule {

    var sharedPreferences = //GET SHARED PREFERENCES THERE

    var authToken: String? = sharedPreferences.getString("Token", null)
    val baseURL = //my base url

    
    val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
        level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
    }


    var httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor { chain ->
        chain.proceed(
            chain.request().newBuilder().also { it.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $authToken") }
                .build()
        )
    }.connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .addNetworkInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
        .build()

    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(baseURL).addConverterFactory(
        GsonConverterFactory.create()
    ).client(httpClient).build()


    val api: API by lazy { retrofit.create() }
    val apiClient = ApiClient(api)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access `SharedPreferences` **anywhere** from your app using `ApplicationContext`. It is a very common practice in Android Development and it is very safe.

To access `ApplicationContext` see code below:

1. In your `Application` class, add an `Application Singleton`.

   ```
   class MyApplication : Application() {
        override fun onCreate() {
           super.onCreate()
           instance = this
        }

        companion object {
            lateinit var instance: MyApplication
                private set
        }
   }
   ```

   ([What is an Application Class?](https://medium.com/droid-log/android-application-class-a8a1d64c82d1))
2. Use `ApplicationContext` anywhere within your app!

   ```
   var sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext() //here you go!
   ```

This code does the job, **however**, if you are interested in **Best Android development practices**, please read this:

**Recommended 2 Options**

1. **Best Practice**: Create a new Manager class that is responsible for app's entire `SharedPreferences` usage (ex. `SharedPreferenceManager`). This class is a `Singleton` Class that is instantiated with `ApplicationContext` and has all the methods related CRUD operations in `SharedPreferences`, in your case `setToken` and  `getToken`. Since the manager class is independent, it should not cause any `Lifecycle` errors or `NullPointer` errors.

   Since attaching sample code will clutter my answer, I decided to cite [someone else's code here, this will teach you how to implement it.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40347393/12301279)
2. **If you are too lazy to follow #2**: You can use a library that has done that for you already: [Pixplicity/EasyPrefs](https://github.com/Pixplicity/EasyPrefs).

   - Easy to use like `Manager` Class ✅
   - No more errors related to `SharedPreferences` ✅
   - You could always retrofit into any existing project ✅

Let me know if you have any questions. Thanks.

Comment: This code won't work for the singleton. You never set the variable to anything. And there's no reason to make the public property nullable, since it won't ever be null after Application is created. And it's not in a companion object. Here's a proper way to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37412029/506796

Comment: @Tenfour04 yup forgot to make it a companion object! fixed it.

Comment: @minchaej, Thank you! I think it is what I was searching for, but I didn't understanded properly. I did this steps with the library that you gave: 
1. Created class PrefsApplication with the given code(just in random place)
2. Tried to use Prefs.putString("Token","myAuthToken")
In logcat:
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Prefs class not correctly instantiated. Please call Builder.setContext().build() in the Application class onCreate.
I think I did a mistake with PrefsApplication class. Where should I create this class(inside of Application.java???) and what to do after? Thank you!!

Comment: @AndreyArshavin Sure thank you for your comment. From my understanding, it sounds like you have not instantiated `Application` Class properly. Have you checked out my URL for you about `Applicaion` Class? (https://medium.com/droid-log/android-application-class-a8a1d64c82d1)

Answer (score 0):

Use these in actual implementations:

```
actual typealias PlatformContext = Activity  //Android

actual typealias PlatformContext = NSObject  //iOS
```

This is a great tutorial to achieve this and solved my problem:
[UserDefaults and SharedPreference in KMM](https://atul-sharma-94062.medium.com/userdefault-and-sharedpreference-in-kotlin-multiplatform-mobile-kmm-490494ba44a6)