# Custom Button in Title Bar of Dialog

Tags: java, android, xml, dialog, titlebar

I'm trying to make a dialog box, similar to the one in Nova Launcher (top right of dialog box):

[image]

To show the settings of the app. I cannot make it show, my current dialog box just shows a normal title bar:
Current code:

Custom dialog box file: (add_dialog_custom_title)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="15.0dip"
    android:paddingRight="15.0dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="0.0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?android:listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:text="@string/menu_item_add_item"
        android:drawablePadding="14.0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@id/settings_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
        android:layout_weight="0.0" />
</LinearLayout>
```

NfcUnlockActivity:

```
package com.quinny898.gcse.doorcontrol;
import android.app.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.text.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;

public class NfcUnlockActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder;
        AlertDialog alertDialog;
    Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog (mContext);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_dialog_custom_title,
    (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));


    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.add_dialog_custom_title);
    dialog.setTitle("Door Control");
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    builder.setView(layout);
    alertDialog = builder.create();
    }
}
```

All the IDs and strings are there, I checked
I feel like I'm missing something really stupid here, any help?

EDIT:
Fixed it, I did what you said and then added 
alertDialog.show();
and then I used the second answer here to fix the resulting crash: [Android: ProgressDialog.show() crashes with getApplicationContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561803/android-progressdialog-show-crashes-with-getapplicationcontext)
Works perfectly, thanks for your help

Comment: Hello, what does the layout_root refers to? Can't seem to get this working, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One mistake is in your image view you have written

```
android:id="@id/settings_button"
```

instead of

```
android:id="@+id/settings_button"
```

Answer (score 1):

That maybe because of the reason that your image is not getting inflated on the dialog box you created, to inflate it, use android:id = "@+id/settings_button" instead of "@id/setting_button"