# Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Tags: android, dialog, android-asynctask, spinner, layout-inflater

hi im trying to inflate an view(B.xml)(which has spinner in it)from a AsyncTask's onPostExecute() in a view(A.xml)mainActivity

MainActivity.class

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.B, null);
        branded_spinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.Spinner01);

        adapter_branded = new ArrayAdapter<String>(**MainActivity.this**,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Branded);
        adapter_branded.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        branded_spinner.setAdapter(adapter_branded);                        
        branded_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(**MainActivity.this**);
```

}

it works fine for 4.0 and Above

but for 2.3.3
im getting an error

```
11-30 15:28:55.492: E/AndroidRuntime(540): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
11-30 15:28:55.492: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:531)
11-30 15:28:55.492: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
11-30 15:28:55.492: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
```

yes i tried to use getApplicationContext() , this  but still the same error

i referred

[Dialog throwing "Unable to add window — token null is not for an application” with getApplication() as context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796611/dialog-throwing-unable-to-add-window-token-null-is-not-for-an-application-wi)

[Android: ProgressDialog.show() crashes with getApplicationContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561803/android-progressdialog-show-crashes-with-getapplicationcontext)

[Android 1.6: "android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634991/android-1-6-android-view-windowmanagerbadtokenexception-unable-to-add-window)

Comment: i get error when i click on the spinner

Comment: Did you absolutely sure that you can use  `ApplicationContext` for drawing? Have you tried to get `LayoutInflater`object instance via `LayoutInflater.from(context)` static constructor(when `context` is a context of your activity)?

Comment: yes every thing is in the snippet i hv given

Comment: Ok, try to use constructor like this for you `vi` variable: `LayoutInflater vi = LayoutInflater.from(YourActivityName.this);`

Comment: yes it worked..Thanks Evos
was stuck on it from long time...

Comment: No problem, i will move my comment to an answer and it will be greate if you will mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, try to use constructor like this for you `vi` variable: `LayoutInflater vi = LayoutInflater.from(YourActivityName.this);`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass only LayoutInflater.from(this);