# Show ProgressDialog in Fragment class

Tags: android, android-fragments, progressdialog

I am trying to show a `ProgressDialog` within a `Fragment` class. The following code just works within an `Activity` class but not for `Fragment`. Can somebody please help me on this, why this `ProgressDialog` implementaion just works within an `Activity` and not for a `Fragment`?

```
private class ProcessUpdateProfile extends
        AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

    private ProgressDialog nDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        nDialog = new ProgressDialog(PFragment.this); //Here I get an error: The constructor ProgressDialog(PFragment) is undefined
        nDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
        nDialog.setTitle("Checking Network");
        nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        nDialog.setCancelable(true);
        nDialog.show();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Try this in `Fragment`

```
 nDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
```

Answer (score 15):

`ProgressDialog` take `Context` input so use `getActivity()` in object creation.

```
ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Loading...", "Please wait...", true);
```